# Why does Querydsl not translate java.time.* columns when in an shaded jar?

Tags: java, maven, querydsl, java-time, maven-shade-plugin

I'm using Querydsl and have a column represented by a `java.time.LocalDate`. This works fine when running via the IDE but fails when run from a jar created by the maven shade plugin. It just returns a `java.sql.Date` object instead.

Why is there a difference and how can I get the shaded jar to return the correct type?

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the combination between the maven shade plugin's `minimizeJar` option and how Querydsl's `com.querydsl.sql.JavaTypeMapping` loads it's mapping of Java types.

The `minimizeJar` option removes all classes that aren't directly referenced. So if a class isn't referenced directly and only gets loaded by it's name, it won't be included in the jar.

The `com.querydsl.sql.JavaTypeMapping` contains a mapping of Java types that classes can be translated to. Most of these are referenced directly, but a few (the JSR310... classes) aren't, they're loaded by class name.

The combination of the two means that the JSR310... classes don't get added to the shaded jar, `com.querydsl.sql.JavaTypeMapping` can't find them and resorts to returning the original `java.sql.*` date/time types.

To fix this, add the following to the `configuration` section of the maven shade plugin

```
<filters>
  ...
  <filter>
    <artifact>com.querydsl:querydsl-sql</artifact>
    <includes>
      <include>**</include>
    </includes>
  </filter>
  ...
<filters>
```

This will force the shade plugin to include every class in the querydsl-sql package (including the JSR310... classes) allowing them to be seen and used by it's mapping class.

- Answering my own question because I spent a lot of time tracking this down and hopefully it'll save other people spending time on it too.