# Querydsl`s JPASQLQuery uses java.sql.Date instead of java.time.LocalDate

Tags: querydsl, java-time, localdate, hibernate-5.x, jsr310

I have a simple PostgreSQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test_entity (
    id int8 NOT NULL,
    title varchar NOT NULL,
    created_at date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test_entity_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Entity for that table and DTO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_entity")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class TestEntity {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "title")
   private String title;

   @Column(name = "created_at")
   private LocalDate createdAt;
   
   ...equals and hashcode...
}

@Data
public class TestEntityDto {
   private Long id;
   private String title;
   private LocalDate createdAt;
}
```

All builds fine and after build I have QTestEntity class:

```
@Generated("com.querydsl.codegen.DefaultEntitySerializer")
public class QTestEntity extends EntityPathBase<TestEntity> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1443624162L;

    public static final QTestEntity testEntity = new QTestEntity("testEntity");

    public final DatePath<java.time.LocalDate> createdAt = createDate("createdAt", java.time.LocalDate.class);

    public final NumberPath<Long> id = createNumber("id", Long.class);

    public final StringPath title = createString("title");

    public QTestEntity(String variable) {
        super(TestEntity.class, forVariable(variable));
    }

    public QTestEntity(Path<? extends TestEntity> path) {
        super(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
    }

    public QTestEntity(PathMetadata metadata) {
        super(TestEntity.class, metadata);
    }

}
```

Then I try a simple select query:

```
final QTestEntity qTestEntity = QTestEntity.testEntity;
final JPASQLQuery<TestEntityDto> query = new JPASQLQuery<>(this.db.getEntityManager(), new PostgreSQLTemplates())
      .select(Projections.bean(TestEntityDto.class,
            qTestEntity.id,
            qTestEntity.title,
            qTestEntity.createdAt))
      .from(qTestEntity);

final List<TestEntityDto> rows = query.fetch();
```

And it throw exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.querydsl.core.types.QBean.newInstance(QBean.java:239)
    at com.querydsl.core.support.NumberConversions.newInstance(NumberConversions.java:86)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.FactoryExpressionTransformer.transformTuple(FactoryExpressionTransformer.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.HolderInstantiator.instantiate(HolderInstantiator.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.getResultList(CustomLoader.java:433)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2186)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1204)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.sql.AbstractJPASQLQuery.getResultList(AbstractJPASQLQuery.java:203)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.sql.AbstractJPASQLQuery.fetch(AbstractJPASQLQuery.java:235)
```

Debugger shows that type of createdAt field is java.sql.Date instead of LocalDate.

I found this question ([Why does Querydsl not translate java.time.* columns when in an shaded jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68553158/why-does-querydsl-not-translate-java-time-columns-when-in-an-shaded-jar)) and check in debugger that JSR310 types loads fine in JavaTypeMapping.

Is this a bug in QueryDSL or I do something wrong?

Spring Boot 2.6, QueryDSL 5.0.0, Hibernate 5.6.9

Comment: check the solution that you already shared a link of stackoverflow.

Comment: 1. I dont use maven and shaded jar, gradle copies querydsl jars as is; 2. I checked in debugger that JSR310*Types loads fine, but query dont work in debugger; 3. I tried to manually register type through com.querydsl.sql.Configuration.register(String table, String column, Class<?> javaType) with no luck

Comment: I don't think `JPASQLQuery` was ever upgraded to support JSR 310 dates. I would try to use `JPAQuery` wherever possible, which has proper JSR 310 support. For native SQL queries I recommend `@NativeQuery` over `JPASQLQuery`.